# How do you print/recall the definition of a function in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, functions

I can define and print the contents of variable called my_var like this:

```
my_var="hello"
echo $my_var
```

but if I define:

```
my_funct {echo "hello";}
```

how can I recall my function's definition later on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `type` command:

```
dennis@lightning:~$ foo() { echo "hi"; }
dennis@lightning:~$ type foo
foo is a function
foo () 
{ 
    echo "hi"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To get just the definition without "foo is a function",

```
$ declare -f foo
foo () 
{ 
    echo "hi"
}
```